# Using JQuery to dynamically insert list items yields different results than hard coded list items...why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created some html that has a couple of different drop down boxes, the first one lets the user select which fields should be viewed in the report, the second one lets them select which months should be viewed on the report.  I started out by hard coding the list items for both drop down boxes, and everything worked as expected.  I assigned a dummy class to both drop downs called "dropdown-menu" so that they could both be referenced by the same javascript function.  For some reason, the "Filter Columns" drop down box won't open in the code snippet I created...but that's not the problem I'm having (so please don't get side tracked on that).

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var options = [];

          $('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(event) {
            console.log(event);
            var $target = $(event.currentTarget),
              val = $target.attr('data-value'),
              column = 'table .' + val,
              $inp = $target.find('input'),
              idx;

            if ((idx = options.indexOf(val)) > -1) {
              options.splice(idx, 1);
              setTimeout(function() {
                $inp.prop('checked', true)
              }, 0);
              $(column).toggle();

              if ($target.find("secondRow")) {
                var cs = $(".topRow").attr("colspan");
                $(".topRow").attr("colspan", parseInt(cs) + 2);
              }
            } else {
              options.push(val);
              setTimeout(function() {
                $inp.prop('checked', false)
              }, 0);
              $(column).toggle();

              if ($target.find("secondRow")) {
                var cs = $(".topRow").attr("colspan");
                $(".topRow").attr("colspan", parseInt(cs) - 2);
              }
            }

            $(event.target).blur();

            return false;
          });
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-1 button-group" style="padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>&nbsp;Filter Columns&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="small" data-value="attRate">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />&nbsp;Attendance Rate</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="small" data-value="enrDays">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />&nbsp;Ttl Enrollment Days</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="small" data-value="msdDays">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />&nbsp;Ttl Missed Days</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="small" data-value="lstRev">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />&nbsp;Lost Revenue</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="small" data-value="lstHrs">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />&nbsp;Instrl Hrs Lost</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-md-1 button-group" style="padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>&nbsp;Select Months&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul id="ddStudentMonths" class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
</div>
```

In my code, when a "Filter Columns" value gets selected, the console.log event is triggered and shows me it is a mouse event.  However, in the dynamically inserted "Select Months" drop down box, the console.log event never gets reached when a value is selected.  In the above code snippet, this is what I see when I click "View Source", it does not show the dynamically insert list items.  However, I can open the drop down box and see the items, and I can also see them when I'm debugging through the code.  I'm guessing this is where the problem is occurring, and where I'm kind of stumped.

To populate the student months drop down box, I'm calling the following javascript function:

```
function getStudentMonths(pID) {
//pID is the page ID as stored in the table dmcPages
var param = { pageID: pID };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    url: "../WebServices/myDates.asmx/getStudentMonths",
    data: JSON.stringify(param),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        var data = [];

        data.push(msg.d);

        for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
            $('#ddStudentMonths').append(data[i]);
        }

    }
})
```

};

The webmethod is constructing the list item strings, and I've verified that they look exactly like the hard-coded list items.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Is the nutshell "why aren't events added to my newly-created elements"? If so, this is a dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickly try this:

Change this

`$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(event) {`

to this:

`$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu a', function(event) {`

and report back to see if that did the trick?

The reason for the change is; Yes, `.on()` is supposed to work for dynamically created elements, but there's not great literature on the fact that your `.on('click'...` is on an element that did not exist in the DOM in the first place.  That's why we use `$(document)` to listen for the click even, since the document is there always, every time.  Then we specify what you're clicking on by adding the class inside the `.on()` function.

Comment: Might be better to attach the handler to the dropdown menu and target its anchors, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I definitely agree, though for his purposes he's using the anchor tag to as a selector.  I just wanted to explain the better way to use `.on()`

Comment: You sir, are a genius!!  That fixed the issue perfectly!!

Comment: A couple of follow-up things:

1. I tried attaching the handler to anchor events -- it worked partially.  The javascript above keeps the dropdown box open until they click somewhere outside of the box, so the user can make one round of selecting and not have to keep opening the box.
2.  How do I mark your answer as correct?  I don't think I have enough points to do it :(

Comment: figured it out...i was making things too hard :)

but to follow up with the attaching the handler to the dropdown menu -- I'd consider myself an "upper level novice" when it comes to my code skills, but I'm always wanting to learn the best/more appropriate way to do things.  So is there a better way to do this, that I should be trying?

Comment: @JimmyGenslinger, So you should be able to attach it to the `select` box itself.  You could try using `.blur()` (which means when they come out of focus from that element) or `.change()` which will fire when the option to the select box is changed.  I think I'm understanding appropriately?